# How to Retrieve Nearest Conversion Timestamp

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I’m trying to assign a pseudo_identifier to a pageview event, specifically using the timestamp of the next subsequent conversion event in the below code. However, if there are multiple conversions within a session_key I’m seeing a row for each pageview per conversion timestamp. How can this be changed so it only returns one value per pageview (the next nearest conversion timestamp within a session_key)? If there are no subsequent conversions after a pageview or a session_key has no conversions, then this should be null.

```
with conversion_events as (
 select 
 session_key,
 event_name, 
 event_timestamp
 FROM `lunar-brace-354914.dev_ga4_main.final_ga4__events`
 WHERE event_date_dt between "2023-10-18" AND "2023-10-20"
 AND is_conversion_event = 1
), 
pageviews as (
 select 
 session_key, 
 event_key,
 event_timestamp, 
 page_location, 
 FROM `lunar-brace-354914.dev_ga4_main.final_ga4__events`
 WHERE event_date_dt between "2023-10-18" AND "2023-10-20"
 AND event_name = "page_view"
), 
pageviews_before_conversion as (
 select
 pageviews.session_key,
 pageviews.event_key,
 pageviews.event_timestamp,
 LEAD(conversion_events.event_timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY pageviews.session_key ORDER BY pageviews.event_timestamp) as pseudo_identifier,
 pageviews.page_location,
 (case when (pageviews.event_timestamp < conversion_events.event_timestamp) then true else false end) as is_before_conversion_event
from pageviews
full outer join conversion_events on conversion_events.session_key = pageviews.session_key
)
select * from pageviews_before_conversion where session_key = "RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg=="
```

Adding a window function to get the next conversion timestamp, but this outputs a conversion timestamp for each pageview

**Example Data:**

| session_key | event_key | event_timestamp | pseudo_identifier | page_location | is_before_conversion_event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | gouDigBKky4W/S2fsLIc7w== | 1697620890597692 | 1697621136844226 | /account/forgot-password | TRUE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | gouDigBKky4W/S2fsLIc7w== | 1697620890597692 | 1697621202423693 | /account/forgot-password | TRUE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | ZX2PmqXKFPRwd9xm28Y67g== | 1697620920543065 | 1697621136844226 | / | TRUE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | ZX2PmqXKFPRwd9xm28Y67g== | 1697620920543065 | 1697621202423693 | / | TRUE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | tNSDGbDR+TT2FIvknDePcQ== | 1697620933253415 | 1697621136844226 | /donate/donate-to-website?type=2&amount=10 | TRUE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | tNSDGbDR+TT2FIvknDePcQ== | 1697620933253415 | 1697621202423693 | /donate/donate-to-website?type=2&amount=10 | TRUE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | UxT8TBovJ0Pkp1fCtHTO5w== | 1697621136844578 | 1697621136844226 | /donate/donate-to-website/thank-you | TRUE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | UxT8TBovJ0Pkp1fCtHTO5w== | 1697621136844578 | 1697621202423693 | /donate/donate-to-website/thank-you | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | 0B/QYHnLK5NXM0dmTBiJfA== | 1697621202423693 | 1697621136844226 | /donate/donate-to-website/thank-you | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | 0B/QYHnLK5NXM0dmTBiJfA== | 1697621202423693 | 1697621202423693 | /donate/donate-to-website/thank-you | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | 2Eoq9Lh9VVedi1fCouH8Sg== | 1697621231609173 | 1697621136844226 | /account/sign-in | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | 2Eoq9Lh9VVedi1fCouH8Sg== | 1697621231609173 | 1697621202423693 | /account/sign-in | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | XivygLkDysd+cADHTtYPqg== | 1697621237578909 | 1697621136844226 | /account/forgot-password | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | XivygLkDysd+cADHTtYPqg== | 1697621237578909 | 1697621202423693 | /account/forgot-password | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | QXlO+6iEBxE7fIpRdm6I3Q== | 1697621348283836 | 1697621136844226 | /account/forgot-password | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | QXlO+6iEBxE7fIpRdm6I3Q== | 1697621348283836 | 1697621202423693 | /account/forgot-password | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | YX7o/3YfwuIV5M60Mjvetg== | 1697621652004893 | 1697621136844226 | /account/forgot-password | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | YX7o/3YfwuIV5M60Mjvetg== | 1697621652004893 | 1697621202423693 | /account/forgot-password | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | xRDKUY8P8BcLIP9KiheEtQ== | 1697621662459196 | 1697621136844226 | /account/sign-in | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | xRDKUY8P8BcLIP9KiheEtQ== | 1697621662459196 | 1697621202423693 | /account/sign-in | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | 79qV+2n1PcBuZX56oG/OWg== | 1697621676479069 | 1697621136844226 | /pet-help-and-advice/our-services?_adal_sd=www.website.org.uk.1697621670022&_adal_ca=so%3dduckduckgo.com%26me%3dreferral%26ca%3dreferral%26co%3dhttps%253A%252F%252Fduckduckgo.com%252F%26ke%3d(not%2520set).1697621670022&_adal_cw=1697557335992.1697621670022&_adal_id=76e2da15-dffa-4ec5-9f9a-1012f2ba9bcb.1697557336.7.1697621657.1697618899.e1ef7096-322f-42ee-86a8-eb0876640093.1697621670022&alias=services | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | 79qV+2n1PcBuZX56oG/OWg== | 1697621676479069 | 1697621202423693 | /pet-help-and-advice/our-services?_adal_sd=www.website.org.uk.1697621670022&_adal_ca=so%3dduckduckgo.com%26me%3dreferral%26ca%3dreferral%26co%3dhttps%253A%252F%252Fduckduckgo.com%252F%26ke%3d(not%2520set).1697621670022&_adal_cw=1697557335992.1697621670022&_adal_id=76e2da15-dffa-4ec5-9f9a-1012f2ba9bcb.1697557336.7.1697621657.1697618899.e1ef7096-322f-42ee-86a8-eb0876640093.1697621670022&alias=services | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | swtadZiXsSAyjlMyz+lpmQ== | 1697621693704388 | 1697621136844226 | /pet-help-and-advice/our-services/website-pet-hospital-services | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | swtadZiXsSAyjlMyz+lpmQ== | 1697621693704388 | 1697621202423693 | /pet-help-and-advice/our-services/website-pet-hospital-services | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | K9/xlhoRbNIuwJdbG7KESA== | 1697621703948614 | 1697621136844226 | /pet-help-and-advice/vet-call-back-request | FALSE |
| RV4IkjWU8LLWyGm1UCjTMg== | K9/xlhoRbNIuwJdbG7KESA== | 1697621703948614 |  | /pet-help-and-advice/vet-call-back-request | FALSE |

Comment: Can you please add example data?

Comment: You should use "union all" instead of full join though.

Comment: @SabriKaragönen I've added the outputted data. As you can see there is a new row for each conversion timestamp (pseudo_indentifier), but I want one row per event_key, which returns the timestamp of the closest conversion

Comment: Since you hashed the events, I can't produce what you want. Can you please provide a simpler and easier to copy data?